# Create a pointable first-person shooter gun using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've been trying to find way to render a result of how to make a gun out of canvas that can point to where the cursor is. I have a basic idea of what I should do:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Block Shooter</title>
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div id="introContainer"><h1 id="intro">Welcome to Block Shooter</h1></div>
            <button id="skip" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left:610px">Skip Intro</button>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
            <script>

            // Variables

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var gunWidth = 80;
            var gunLength = 150;

            $("#canvas").mousemove(function (event) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = gunWidth;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2 - gunWidth / 2, canvas.height + 100);
                ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = gunWidth;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
                ctx.moveTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2 - gunWidth / 2, canvas.height - gunLength);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

            })

            </script>
        </center>
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't know what I should do next. Is there a better way of doing this? If so, please provide an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately interactive graphics programming quickly gets into math....
Replace what you have in your $(#canvas).mousemove( function with the following

```
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = gunWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            //get dimensions of canvas
           //for performance this should be moved out of the
            //mousemove and up to where your other global variables canvas and ctx are. 
            var dimensions=event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            var middle=dimensions.left+(dimensions.width/2)
            ctx.moveTo(middle,0);
            //get mousex relative to canvas
            var mousex=event.clientX-dimensions.left;
            //get mousey relative to canvas 
            var mousey=event.clientY-dimensions.top;
            var ydistance=mousey;
            var xdistance=mousex-middle
            //distance formula 
            var distance=Math.sqrt((xdistance*xdistance)+(ydistance*ydistance))
            //http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175896/finding-a-point-along-a-line-a-certain-distance-away-from-another-point
            var gunlength=200;
            var drawx=(gunlength*(xdistance/distance))+middle
            var drawy=gunlength*(ydistance/distance)

            ctx.lineTo(drawx, drawy);


            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
```

That will make the gun stay the same size....
You'll have change some things to get the gun back to the bottom of the canvas ( HTML canvas has an inverted y-axis and I didn't account for that in the demo)

Comment: How would I get the gun back? I've tried moving the moveTo to the bottom but then what?